# How to get acknowledge and stop sending data

Tags: python, xbee

With the [python-xbee](http://code.google.com/p/python-xbee/) library, I have written code to send data from end point to coordinator. I have successfully sent data to the coordinator and coordinator receives that data. But, in the end point code, after the coordinator gets the data, I want to end communication. What should I write so that I can detect that the coordinator has recieved the data?

I am sending data with

```
 class XbeeSend(Concurrent):
    def __init__(self):
            self.stopped = False
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        try: 
            while self.stopped == False :
                    data_ = str( .... ) 
                    xbee.send('tx',frame_id='\x01',dest_addr_long=DEST_ADDR_LONG,dest_addr="\xff\xfe",data=data_)
                    time.sleep(1)
                    threading.Timer(2, self.run())
        except:
                    None
```

Answer (score 1):

You should receive a "transmit status" message (frame type 0x88) of SUCCESS on the sending node when the coordinator has received your message.  This is a low-level status message that the radio (XBee module) has received the message, and doesn't guarantee that your application layer has actually processed the message.

If, for example, your application had crashed but the XBee was still powered up, you would still see the transmit status of SUCCESS.

I don't know how you would configure `python-xbee` to receive copies of the transmit status messages.  You would need to update your code to use an incrementing frame ID (1 to 255 and back to 1) and keep a table of recently sent frames.  Match the frame ID referenced in the transmit status message with your table to know what frames have been received.

The `python-xbee` library should have a mode where it uses a new frame ID for each message sent, and provides that information to you for use in your table.